# How can I use positional parameter while the number of position is a special parameter in one time command?

Tags: bash

I'd like to open bash and get the last positional parameter.
So I tried this one:

```
bash -cv 'echo $$#' -- 1 2 'The Third'
```

My idea is to use `$#` to get to know the number of arguments.
Because there are 3 arguments here - 1, 2 and 'The Third', `$#` should be 3 and `$$#` should become `$3` and return 'The Third' to me.

But it turns out that `$$` being evaluated first whose value is shell process id.

I searched for some while and I get this solution:

```
bash -cv 'eval echo \${$#}' -- 1 2 'The Third'
```

It works but it feels like I split one command into two.
Expansion first and eval second.

Is it possible to do it in one time command?
Like

```
bash -cv 'echo $($#)' -- 1 2 'The Third'
```

to set priority between expansions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea was okay, but that's not how you write it in bash syntax. Use "indirect expansion", introduced with the exclamation sign:

```
bash -cv 'echo ${!#}' -- 1 2 'The Third'
# => The Third
```

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter}`
>
> The value of parameter is substituted.  The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter  is  followed by a character which is not to be interpreted as part of its name.
>
> If  the first character of parameter is an exclamation point, a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter  itself. This  is  known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions of `${!prefix*}` and `${!name[@]}` described below.  The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

Comment: Thank you. I also like to know if I want to get last second argument, in this case it is `2`, any solution based on `bash -cv 'echo ${!#}' -- 1 2 'The Third'` ?

Comment: Not really. Based on the above, the closest I can think of is `bash -cv 'n=$(($# - 1)); echo "${!n}"' -- 1 2 'The Third'`; but this would be simpler: `bash -cv 'echo "${@: -2:1}"' -- 1 2 'The Third'` (slice one element from the second element from the back)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `bash`

```
bash -cv 'echo "${@: -1}"' -- 1 2 'The Third'
```

```
echo "${@: -1}"
The Third
```

Or you may use an array to store all arguments first:

```
bash -cv 'arr=("$@"); echo "${arr[@]: -1}"' -- 1 2 'The Third'
```

```
arr=("$@"); echo "${arr[@]: -1}"
The Third
```